# Rolling Upgrade Application Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: java, glassfish, admin, glassfish-3, java-6

I saw a turorial video about rolling updates on glassfish 3.1

http://parleys.com/play/514892290364bc17fc56c463/chapter49/about

They used a param called --rolling-upgrade but i cannot find it in the param list of deploy sub-command. Does s.b. know what happend to it?
--keepstate, which is also mentioned, is existsing.

```
Usage: asadmin [asadmin-utility-options] deploy
    [--target[=<target(default:server)>]]
    [--virtualservers <virtual_servers>] [--contextroot <context_root>]
    [--force[=<force(default:false)>]]
    [--precompilejsp[=<precompilejsp(default:false)>]]
    [--verify[=<verify(default:false)>]] 
    [--name <component_name>]
    [--upload[=<upload(default:false)>]] 
    [--retrieve <local_dirpath>]
    [--dbvendorname <dbvendorname>]
    [--createtables[=createtables(default:false)>] | --dropandcreatetables[=dropandcreatetables(default:false)>]]
    [--uniquetablenames[=<uniquetablenames(default:false)>]]
    [--deploymentplan <deployment_plan>]
    [--enabled[=<enabled(default:true)>]]
    [--availabilityenabled[=<availabilityenabled(default:false)>]]
    [--lbenabled[=<lbenabled(default:true)>]]
    [--asyncreplication[=<asyncreplication(default:true)>]]
    [--keepstate[=<keepstate(default:false)>]]
    [--generatermistubs[=<generatermistubs(default:false)>]]
    [--libraries jar_file[,jar_file*]] 
    [--type <pkg-type>]
    [--properties (name=value)[:name=value]*]
    [-?|--help[=<help(default:false)>]] file_archive | filepath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is what I think it is (I haven't watch the video), then this was a prototype at the time. Marian Mueller of Serli, the speaker, is one of the engineers behind this feature.  This is now called "[production redeployment](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/ProductionRedeployment)", and the contribution is planned for a future GlassFish 4 release.  I do have to give kudos to Serli for their efforts and contribution to the GlassFish community.

Comment: found a way to do it. first deploy without enabling and then enable on each instance separately